# Has archaeological dating been attempted on Ramayana sites?

Tags: ramayana, history

In India, Nepal and Sri Lanka, there are many sites that are linked with Ramayana. Many are said to have been established by Gods themselves.

Have there been any attempts to archaeologically date these sites? The events depicted must have happened during or before the establishment of these sites.

If they have been dated, then we can know with certainty "*at the very least*" how old Ramayana events are.

This would also help with figuring out the ancient history of India & Sri Lanka.

---

Addition 1:
The Koneswaram Shivan Temple in Trincomalee / "Sri Kona Mountain", Sri Lanka is said to have been worshiped and patronized by Ravana. The first temple sunk under the sea in Tsunami in BC 306. Current temple at the site is the third one.

Comment: Rama Setu has been dated by NASA.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Actually this is a misconception; NASA has denied rumors that it dated the bridge: http://www.hindustantimes.com/science/photos-no-proof-of-ram-setu-nasa/article1-247912.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

The answer is clearly NO.  There is no carbon dating on those archaeological sites.  According to certain exalted hindu saints and Yogis of highest order, Ramayana & Mahabharata are mystic stories, did not actually happen, symbolic of every day in every human body.
Pandavas = five senses, Draupadi = sixth sense
Kauravas = 100 bad vices
Karna = human ego

Comment: At the moment there are no source references for your answer which makes it your opinion only. Do you have sources?